# How to get JSON response from PHP into store on form submission in ExtJS?

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

I have a Login form with username & password fields, after submitting the form, My app is redirecting to the PHP response. Here I want to get the JSON response to get loaded into a store and the app shouldn't get redirected to PHP file which is returning JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

In php write

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

In ExtJs you need write method that will be do request to your php

Answer (score 0):

//Ext Js

```
loginForm.submit({
    success: function(form, action){
        switch(action.result.status)
        {
            case 'ok'    : document.location = 'index.php'; break;
            case 'failed': 
                login_info.setHTML(action.result.msg); 
                login_info.show();
            break;
        }        
    },
    failure: function(form, action){
        login_info.setHTML('Communication error with the server'); 
        login_info.show();
    }
});
```

//php

```
if( $condition ){
    // login success    
    $response = array('success'=>true, 'status'=>'ok', 'msg'=>'');
}else{
    //failure
    $response = array('success'=>true, 'status'=>'failed', 'msg'=>utf8_encode('User or password incorrect'));
}
echo json_encode($response);
```